# How many ways of selection?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, permutations, combinations, arithmetic-progressions

In how many ways can you select 3 distinct numbers from a set of *x* distinct **natural numbers** (the set is starting from 1 and ending at *x*) such that the 3 numbers that you selected are in **arithmetic progression**?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @callculus All I can think of is there are xC3 ways of selecting 3 numbers randomly. Now if i keep on increasing the common difference with a fixed first term of the arithmetic progression, i would get my answer, but in a very lengthy way. I want a shorter and a generalized form to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If three numbers a,b,c are in an Arithmetic Progression, then it follows that $b=\dfrac{a+c}{2}$. Since $b$ is an integer, $a+c$ must be even: Which further means that there are 2 cases for $a$ and $c$: Which I leave for you to find. As Christian Blatter pointed out, $a$ and $c$ completely determine the triple.

Comment: This implies 2b=a+c which means that the sum (a+c) should be even. Now, either (a) and (c) both can be odd numbers or both can be even numbers. But the problem for me is, what next? How to find the number of ways of selection?

Comment: So you want to select 2 numbers from the set of Odd no.s, OR, 2 numbers from the set of even no.s.

Comment: So if x is even, the answer is:              2*((x/2)C(2)). And if x is odd, the answer is:  {[(x+1)/2]C2}+{[(x-1)/2]C2}. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.